# Can you use Dropbox API to read / write json in production?

Tags: dropbox

I'm making a small website to be used for a single day at a tradeshow.  The site will only be on 5 machines concurrently.  Is there any reason I can't use my access token to read and write json to store user data as they use the website?  (Users don't need to have an individual accounts.  They'll be asked to type in their name and their data will be saved to an aggregate file given to a company.)  I'm wondering if there will be bandwidth concerns?  I imagine at most there will be 150 read or write requests an hour.  Are there other things I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/using-dropbox-api-to-read-and-write-json-in-production-race/m-p/369086#M20839 ]

[The Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) can certainly be used to upload and download files of any type.

One thing to note though is that the Dropbox API was designed with the intention that each user would link their own Dropbox account, in order to interact with their own files. It sounds like you want your app to always connect to one specific Dropbox account though, for all end-users.

It is technically possible to connect to just one account. The SDKs don't offer explicit support for it and we don't recommend doing so, for various technical and security reasons.

For example, if multiple instances try to write to the same account at the same time, they will likely run in to [lock contention](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/data-ingress-guide).

However if you did go this route, instead of kicking off the authorization flow, you would embed an existing access token for your account and app.